Facebook login issues with OAuth flow
I am attempting to implement Facebook login. I can do the login flow with just URLs and curl, so I know my app is set up correctly in meta developer.
This simple URL returns an auth code, it works:
https://www.facebook.com/v19.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=747816574211556&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flovebotlabs.com%2Foauth&state=987654322
When I call FB.login() it calls this URL, which gives me a something went wrong ambiguous message with no error codes etc:
https://www.facebook.com/v10.0/dialog/oauth?app_id=747816574211556&cbt=1714762070537&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df70402d1e7287ace1%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ff301ca52f8039f8f5%26relation%3Dopener&client_id=747816574211556&display=popup&domain=localhost&e2e=%7B%7D&fallback_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&locale=en_US&logger_id=f42ac630c4cc2b4fd&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df6994ac37ea6bfc58%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ff301ca52f8039f8f5%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df22105be6418ef506&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Cgraph_domain&scope=email%2Cpublic_profile&sdk=joey&version=v10.0
More human readable:

URL: https://www.facebook.com/v10.0/dialog/oauth
app_id: 747816574211556
cbt: 1714762070537
channel_url: https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=f70402d1e7287ace1&domain=localhost&is_canvas=false&origin=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ff301ca52f8039f8f5&relation=opener
client_id: 747816574211556
display: popup
domain: localhost
e2e: {}
fallback_redirect_uri: https://localhost:8080/
locale: en_US
logger_id: f42ac630c4cc2b4fd
origin: 1
redirect_uri: https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=f6994ac37ea6bfc58&domain=localhost&is_canvas=false&origin=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ff301ca52f8039f8f5&relation=opener&frame=f22105be6418ef506
response_type: token, signed_request, graph_domain
scope: email, public_profile
sdk: joey
version: v10.0

It's not specifying the redirect_uri, even though I did specify it in my login code. Also it doesn't seem to be passing state. And it's also a bunch more info.
Here is my login call:

    FB.login(
    
                function (response) {
    
                  console.log("logging in with facebook");
    
                  console.log(response);
    
                  this.isSignedIn = response.status === "connected";
    
                },
    
                {
    
                  scope: "email,public_profile",
    
                  redirect_uri: "https://lovebotlabs.com/oauth",
    
                  state: "123456789",
    
                }
    
              );
    
              console.log(response.authResponse);
    
              this.isSignedIn = response.status === "connected";
    
            }); 


What am I doing wrong?

You don't get to specify the redirect URI yourself, when using FB.login. The JS SDK is supposed to handle the whole process for you.
